# How to add fields to a Dialog

Tags: blackberry, textbox, dialog

Iam new in BlackBerry programming. I want to make a `Dialog` with 2 inputtext, 2 labels and OK and Cancel button something like this:

```
|PIN|:|inputtext|
|Bumber|:|inputtext|
|Button(OK)||Button(Cancell)|
```

Comment: |Button(OK)||Button(Cancell)|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Your requirement is nothing but "**Custom Popup**"

For this the below link will help you:

[CustomPopupScreen@WordPress](http://alishaik001.wordpress.com/2013/06/18/blackberry-custom-popup-screenforgot-password-example/)

or

[CustomPopupScreen@BlogSpot](http://alishaik001.blogspot.in/2013/06/blackberry-custom-popup-screenforgot.html)

Check this and change according to your requirement.

Comment: Thank, you... this is what iam looking for. So do you know how can can navigate with screens?? Like replace my MainScreen?? Like call intent in "Android Programming"??/

Comment: are you new to blackberry? Yes, I know. If you remove "extends Popupscreen" to "extends MainScreen" then it shows like screen not like popup screen.

Comment: Please stop posting answers where all the content is on another site.  If that link goes dead, or the URL changes slightly, then this answer becomes useless, since there's no information in it.  If you want to keep a longer answer on your blog, that's fine.  You can link to it here, and post the important parts of your solution directly in your answer.